# Closure inference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Why doesn't this compile:

```
let fullData = [["availabilities": [], "firstSlot": Date()]] as [AnyObject]

let slots = fullData.map { (s) -> [AnyObject] in
    return (s as Dictionary)["availabilities"] as [AnyObject]
}
```

The type of the collection is [AnyObject] so map should be able to infer that "s" is AnyObject. Then there is an explicit cast of the result to [AnyObject] so map should understand that the return is [AnyObject] and the resulting collection [[AnyObject]]

What am I missing?

Comment: `let slots = fullData.compactMap { ($0 as? [String:Any])?["availabilities"] as? [AnyObject] }`

Comment: This does not answer the question "Why doesn't this compile?"

Comment: Because you did not specify the dictionary type [String: Any]. Another thing is that the dictionary value is Any it might fail to cast to an array so you need to conditional cast and use compactMap.

Comment: try `let dict = ["availabilities": [], "firstSlot": Date()] as AnyObject`
`type(of: dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with closures or inference. It seems to be a simple matter of types and casting.

You cannot "sideways cast" an AnyObject to a Dictionary (or to anything else for that matter). You have to force-cast it, using `as!`

Plus, there is no such thing in Swift as a Dictionary plain and simple, because it is a generic. The most general type of dictionary is `[AnyHashable:Any]`.

So the initial cast of `s` needs to be:

```
(s as! [AnyHashable:Any])
```

And by the same token you cannot "sideways cast" the resulting value taken from the dictionary; you must force-cast it:

```
as! [AnyObject]
```

Now you can write the whole line as:

```
return (s as! [AnyHashable:Any])["availabilities"] as! [AnyObject]
```

---

Of course, what you're doing here seems completely crazy; you should not be turning anything into an AnyObject. But perhaps this is a toy example drawn from some other context, e.g. you've got JSON coming in? But in *that* case you should be using Codable to organize the JSON into real objects.

Comment: Well, the question was about why something is not compiling, not about what libraries / practices should be used.

Comment: There's more to life than what the question was. In order to answer your question, I have had to write a line of code that I would never in a million years write in real life. So I have appended a disclaimer.